# adding value to tensorboard for adversarial learning

Tags: tensorflow, merge, tensorboard, summary

I'm new to tensorboard. I have faced some problem while using it.

### Problem 1 :

I'm writing an adversarial learning model. For visualizing the loss of the model I have the following loss,

- `actor loss`
- `critic loss`

for the learning algorithm provided in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661), 
in one(or K) batch I have to feed actor and critic both. Then I need to only feed value to the critic. This time there is no actor. I think, to show value in tensorboard I need to do following,

```py
def model():
    ...
    actor_loss = ...
    tf.summary.scalar('actor', actor_loss)

    ...

    critic_loss = ...
    tf.summary.scalar('critic', critic_loss)



my_graph = tf.Graph()
with my_graph.as_default():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        model()
        merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(address+ '/train',
                               sess.graph)

        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Now while giving input to inner_loop (where actor and critic both participated) there's no problem, we get the result by following,

```py
a,b,c,d,summary = sess.run( [actor_train_step, critic_train_step, actor_loss, critic_loss, merged], feed_dict = feed_dict )
writer.add_summary(summary, batch)
```

but when we want to give input only to the critic, then the code becomes following,

```py
a,b,summary = sess.run( [critic_train_step, critic_loss, merged], feed_dict = feed_dict )
writer.add_summary(summary, batch)
```

But as `merged` have dependency over `actor_loss` it cannot run. On the other side, I can't just feed value to of actor to the model. How how to solve this issue?

### Problem 2

I am not evaluating (calculating the score value) the model by tensor operation. Actually, I generate the output and fed the output to another script and got the score value from there. So after each of the batch/epoch I am evaluating my model and got a score value from the script. How can I save this value to tensorboard?

I can not formalize a `tf.summary.merge_all()` operation before the session initialization as I am calculating the evaluation score value at the training time from outside script.

> Where should I put the `tf.summary.merge_all()` operation?

Now if I want to combine the Problem 1 and Problem 2 to in a single project is there anything new I have to do.

**Note: I'm new to tensorboard. So it will be better if you can give a detailed explanation.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem #1

If you only want to summary only the critic op, you should only run the summary op for the critic part instead of using `tf.summary.merge_all()`

For example:

```
def model():
    ...
    actor_loss = ...
    tf.summary.scalar('actor', actor_loss)

    ...

    critic_loss = ...
    summary_critic = tf.summary.scalar('critic', critic_loss)

a,b,summary = sess.run( [critic_train_step, critic_loss, summary_critic], feed_dict = feed_dict )
writer.add_summary(summary, batch)
```

#### Problem #2

To visualize the values you got after running the outside script. You can convert those values to tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor()`, [which is documented here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor). Then serializing that tensor to visualize it on tensorboard.

For example:

```
vals = output_from_outside_script()
vals_tensor = sess.run(tf.convert_to_tensor(vals))
tf.summary.scalar('evaluation', vals_tensor)
```

Every `tf.summary` operations will create a `Summary` protobuf which serializing your tensor to an events file. And instead of running all the  summary ops, Tensorflow provide `tf.summary.merger_all()` to run all the summary ops in your graph.

I tried to do it in your case.
Outside script:

```
import numpy as np

def output_from_outside_script(var):
    return np.sum(var)
```

Code in adversarial training:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from outside_evaluation import *

sess = tf.Session()

x = sess.run(tf.constant([[1,2,3,4]], dtype=tf.float32))
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 4])
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 10], stddev=0.1))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

val = tf.matmul(a=X, b=W, name='matmul')
tf.summary.scalar('matmul_mean', tf.reduce_mean(val))

y = sess.run(val, feed_dict={X: x})
print('y = ', y)

vals = output_from_outside_script(y)
print('vals = ', vals)
vals_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(vals, name='vals_tensor')
tf.summary.scalar('evaluation', vals_tensor)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join('test_log'), sess.graph)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={X: x})
writer.add_summary(summary)
writer.close()
```

**Output:**

```
('y = ', array([[-0.51137048, -0.16054343, -0.03827953,  0.1124011 ,  0.09200752,
        -0.22235785,  0.41357356,  1.04061067, -0.08877556, -0.86647421]], 
('vals = ', -0.22920817)
```

**Tensorboard log:**
**Scalar:**
[image]

Should there be any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Actually, I didn't understand the internal workflow of the tensorboard. My main concern is when I put `tf.summary.merge_all()` is that mean the all the summary operation **at that time** of the graph merged or it's just worked as an object?

Comment: You can think the `merge_all()` op is a big operation, which will merge(run) all the summary ops in your graph, so you have to make sure that you feed all the needed inputs to your summary ops. And I think, yes **"at that time"**

Comment: so when I call `tf.summary.scalar('evaluation', vals_tensor)` **at that time** my `merged` object does not know about this(`tf.summary.scalar('evaluation', vals_tensor)`). So how can this operation will be merged with my whole graph?

Comment: I am not actually tested this in your case, but I think when you define `vals_tensor` and `tf.summary.scalar('evaluation', vals_tensor)`, you already add these ops to your graph. So if you call `tf.summary.merge_all()` after that, it will work. Please test it with your code.

Comment: Please see the added example. I think it pretty similar to your case.